# How many days will an unanswered question with single up-vote stay?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I read [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222), and actually it is very confusing.

> The system will automatically delete unlocked, unanswered questions
>   with score of zero (**or one if the owner is deleted**), blah blah blah
>   after 365 days.

I didn't understand this words in above sentence: "**one if the owner is deleted**" That is why I am confused; please explain it to me.

Comment: What about it don't you understand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

User can have their account removed for a variety of reasons. Typically, their questions are not removed with the account, so their posts are essentially **anonymous.**

Under the automatic deletion guidelines, anonymous posts have a bit higher bar than other questions to be considered viable.

**For unanswered questions older than one year:**

- **Regular Posts:** Questions with a score <= 0 are removed
- **Anonymous Posts:** Questions with a score <= 1 are removed

Answer (score 3):

Actually this sounds [feature requested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/260388) and now became a part of [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/roomba):

> If the question is more than 365 days old, and ...
>
> - has a score of 0 or less, **or a score of 1 and a deleted owner**
> - has no answers
> - is not locked
> - has view count <= the age of the question in days times 1.5
> - has 1 or 0 comments
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted. These are termed "abandoned" questions (`RemoveAbandonedQuestions`).
>   These checks are run every week across

Here deleted owner means the account of one who posted question is deleted.